# Update Hidden field with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, hidden-field

All,

I have the following code to update the text of a hidden field in my aspx page once a checkbox is clicked:

BiopsyDone:

```
< asp:CheckBox ID ="cbLiverBiopsy" runat="server" Checked="false" OnCheckedChanged="BiopsyResults_SelectedIndexChanged"/> <br/>
    < asp:HiddenField ID="hide" runat="server" Value=" " /> 

 < script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#cbLiverBiopsy").change(function () {
                $("#hide").val("The liver biopsy results were ");
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Once the program is run, the hidden field does not update once the checkbox is clicked. Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Alan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A way to do it with ClientID

```
$('#<%= hide.ClientID %>').val("The liver biopsy results were ");
```

Then it doesn't need to be static

Comment: visit for more info [Control.ClientID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(v=vs.110).aspx) Property

Answer (score 1):

Set `clientidmode="static"` for the hiiden input..

```
< asp:HiddenField ID="hide" runat="server" Value=" " clientidmode="static"/>
```

Access it as..

```
document.getelementid('hide').value="The liver biopsy results were";
```

or

```
$('#<%= hide.ClientID %>').val("The liver biopsy results were ");
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting it by ID

**HTML:**

```
 < asp:HiddenField ID="hide" runat="server" Value=" " />
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#<%= hide.ClientID %>').val("The liver biopsy results were ");
```

For getting it by Class

**HTML:**

```
 < asp:HiddenField ID="hide" class="hideClass" runat="server" Value=" " />
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.hideClass').val("The liver biopsy results were ");
```